# QScrollArea Child Widget size set according to to Parents size change

Tags: qt, visual-c++, qwidget, qscrollarea

I want to fit (child) widget into the parent widget size. So if the parent window is too small to display all the elements of the child widget the QScrollArea should appear otherwise it should be invisible.

I have attached the pictures for a better understanding.

[image]

The black box is where I want my scroll to appear. Since when we reduce the size of the window, sometimes you can't see the scroll bar (as displayed in the below picture) it doesn't look elegant enough for big projects.

[image]

Please help me with the same, thanks in advance.

Here's the sample code that I used for example:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
QApplication a(argc, argv);
QScrollPractice w;

QDialog * dlg = new QDialog(); 
//dlg->setGeometry(100, 100, 260, 260);
dlg->setMinimumSize(150, 200);

QScrollArea *scrollArea = new QScrollArea(dlg);
scrollArea->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn);
scrollArea->setWidgetResizable(true);
//scrollArea->setGeometry(10, 10, 200, 200);
//scrollArea->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Ignored);
//QSizePolicy sizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
scrollArea->setSizePolicy(sizePolicy);

QWidget *widget = new QWidget(scrollArea);
scrollArea->setWidget(widget);

QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout(widget);
widget->setLayout(layout);

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    QPushButton *button = new QPushButton(QString("%1").arg(i));
    layout->addWidget(button);
    }

dlg->show();

return a.exec();
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Dialog is missing a layout as well. Thats the reason the scrollArea Widget isnt spread out across the dialog.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDialog>
#include <QScrollArea>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QDialog* dlg = new QDialog();

    dlg->setMinimumSize(150, 200);

    QScrollArea* scrollArea = new QScrollArea(dlg);
    scrollArea->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn);
    scrollArea->setWidgetResizable(true);

    QWidget* widget = new QWidget(scrollArea);
    scrollArea->setWidget(widget);

    QVBoxLayout* dlgLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
    dlg->setLayout( dlgLayout );
    dlgLayout->addWidget( scrollArea );
    QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout(widget);
    widget->setLayout(layout);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        QPushButton* button = new QPushButton(QString("%1").arg(i));
        layout->addWidget(button);
    }

    dlg->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

I modified your code to make it run and compileable, also I added antoher `QVBoxLayout` and added it to the dialog. Then the `scrollArea` gets added to that Layout. Hope this helps.